# kubernetes command to check how much time has passed after a pod has gone to Terminating state

Tags: kubernetes

I have used `kubectl get pods -n somenamespace` but it gives the `AGE` and not how much time has passed after the pod has gone to terminating state.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the pod name using the following command

```sh
$ kubectl get pods -n somenamespace | grep Terminating
some-pod-7c5d849f6b-qv48m             1/1     Terminating   0          17h
```

Then you can run the following command to get what you need

```sh
$ kubectl describe pod some-pod-7c5d849f6b-qv48m -n somenamespace | grep Terminating
Status:                    Terminating (lasts 3h10m)
```